# How to apply border-radius to image with padding?

Tags: html, css

I have image with white padding in the top and bottom. See attachment please.

When I try to use `border-radius` to this images I get distorted edges.

How can I fix this issue in this case? Because I can not replace image on image without white space.

[image]

[image]

[Snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/tc29nedy/)

Comment: Create a demonstration snippet. Is the padding part of the image?

Comment: No this padding inside image, I mean this is a part of image

Comment: If you know the exact height of the padding inside the images, you could create a workarund that uses the image as a background-image on a container. If you size the container exactly like the "real" image size, and position the background-image correctly, you can then apply the border-radius on that container.

Comment: Snippet: `https://jsfiddle.net/tc29nedy/`

Comment: This a not padding. This a image. Size of white line is static?

Comment: This is not padding , that is part of the image

Comment: Yeah... it's the image itself that is the problem. I'll use paint to crop the image so that the white spaces on the top and bottom is gone.

Comment: If you want round edges, don't use `border-radius: %` use `border-radius: px`

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the exact height of the padding inside the images, you could create a workarund that uses the image as a background-image on a container. If you size the container exactly like the "real" image size, and position the background-image correctly, you can then apply the border-radius on that container.

```css
.imagecontainer {
  background: url(http://nafantano.com/image/cache/catalog/toys/2017/img_8356____by_nafantano-d9aagdh-399x287.jpg) no-repeat 0 -10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 230px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="imagecontainer"></a>
```

> https://jsfiddle.net/tc29nedy/5/

Answer (score 2):

Here is my proposal:

```
<div class="image hovereffect">
                <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="https://theimgurl" id="featured_55">
 </a></div>
```

Use in css the overflow:hidden for the image class and the image img need a margin-top:-10.

```
.image {
  width:300px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius:20px;
  overflow:hidden;

  }

.image img {
margin-top:-10px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You Can TRY**

```css
img {
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://wallpapercave.com/wp/206q0ew.jpg" style="height:250px;">
```

Comment: You have not understood the problem.